# What ways can I put a FAVICON into my site?

Tags: javascript, html, favicon

I was looking around the web at the way different sites put their favicon into the site. Whenever I try to do it myself I end up "hacking" until it just suddenly decides to work.

I suppose I have 2 questions in one here.

1. How is this site adding it's favicon? - http://www.fbd.ie

   I can't find favicon.ico in it's page source.
2. Apart from including `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">`, how can I include a favicon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It probably just has a file called `favicon.ico` in the root directory of the website.  Most browsers will just look there by default regardless of if there is a `<link>` tag or not.
2. See answer to #1.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to add a favicon is to simply put a file named `favicon.ico` into the root directory of your web site.

Browsers will find it automatically.

You can also specifically put in a `<link>` tag.  Any of these will work:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://example.com/image.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/image.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://example.com/image.gif">
```

Edit:  I see you knew that already.  :D

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is include the file in the root of your site. Browsers are designed to request this *automatically* - you will see a large number of requests for it 404ing in your web logs if you don't have one!.

From wikipedia:

> The original means of defining a
>   favicon, introduced in Internet
>   Explorer 4, was by placing a file
>   called favicon.ico in the root
>   directory of a web server. This would
>   then automatically be used in Internet
>   Explorer's favorites (bookmarks)
>   display. Later, however, a more
>   flexible system was created using HTML
>   to indicate the location of an icon
>   for any given page. As detailed below,
>   this is achieved by adding a link
>   element to the  section of the
>   document which specifies the type of
>   the image file and its location. In
>   this way any image file defined by the
>   standard may be used.

The salient point is that you don't have to do anything in your HTML mark-up or any other resource file. Just dump the file in the root.